# How to prove by contrapositive

Tags: discrete-mathematics

By proving the contrapositive, prove that, if n^2 is not divisible by 5, then n is not divisible by 5.

Comment: Write the contrapositive.

Comment: Suppose $n$ *is* divisible by $5$.  Does that imply anything about $n^2$?

Comment: Hint : Contrapositive of if $p$ then $q$ is if not $q$ then not $p$.

Answer (score 1):

You want to prove $5\nmid n^2\Rightarrow 5\nmid n$. The contrapositive of this statement is $5\mid n\Rightarrow 5\mid n^2$. Clearly this holds. Take for example, $5\mid 10$ as $5\times 2=10$, therefore $5\times 2\times 10=100=10^2$.

You have to remember that the contrapositive of $A\Rightarrow B$ is $\overline{B}\Rightarrow \overline A$. Sometimes, you can make a prove easy by taking the contrapositive, your question is an example of this.